# Excel VBA Return true or false if 10 rows match a certain criteria

Tags: vba, excel

**Situation:**
I make reports for Surgery Rooms and give them clearance for usage if they meet certain criteria or not. One of those criteria is that about 1 million particals per minute are allowed to flow in/out of the room. The partical counters that are used to measure this, output a data sheet that can be opened in excel. Every minute the machine is counting particals it adds a new row to the data table displaying how many particals it counted.

Inorder to give the Surgery Room clearance for usage the counter must out put nearly the exact same 1 million (offset by 10.000 particals +- allowed) particals for 10 minutes straight.

**What do I need:**
I need a code that can compare the first 10 rows of data (starting from row:3). If they meet the criteria(with an offset of 10.000) fill the cells of those rows vbGreen. If they don't match, go to the next row (row:4) and compare the next 10 rows. If they match fill those rows vbGreen. If they don't match move to the next row (row:5), so on.

If no match was made then fill cellA1 vbRed.

**Example Table:**
The 0.3 micron(counts) row is the one we want to compare. The top row of this table is row number 3 in excel. In Cell C1 I should be able to enter this required value (now assumed to be 1 million). And cell A1, as previously said, should turn vbRed if there are no matches.

```
Time Stamp | Location 2 | Location 2 | Location 2 | Location 2 | Location 2
-----------| 0.3 micron | 0.3 micron | 0.5 micron | 0.5 micron | Temerature
-----------| (counts)   | (p/ft^3)   | (counts)   | (p/ft^3)   | (F)       
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1555000   | 186600000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  800000    | 96000000.0 |    400000  | 48000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1555000   | 186600000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.6
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1010000   | 121200000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1009000   | 121080000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1003000   | 120360000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |   991000   | 118920000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.6
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1008000   | 120960000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1009000   | 121080000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1010000   | 121200000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1004000   | 120480000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1000000   | 120000000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1002000   | 120240000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.2
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
7/6/2016   |  1014000   | 121680000.0|    800000  | 96000000.0 | 75.6
___________|____________|____________|____________|____________|____________
```

**Continued:**
I have no idea where to start or how a function like this would be called. This website has taught me alot, but I am unable to find and create anything like this.

I am open to any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could `AutoFilter()`, like follows (see comments to adjust code to your actual needs):

```
Sub main()
    Dim area As Range
    Dim ppm As Double
    Dim found As Boolean

    With Worksheets("Rooms") '<--| change "Rooms" to your actual worksheet name
        ppm = .Range("C1").Value
        With .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| assuming data are in columns A to F and start at row 3 -.> headres in row 2
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & ppm * 0.9, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & ppm * 1.1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
                For Each area In .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
                    If area.Rows.count > 9 Then
                        area.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                        found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1").Interior.Color = IIf(found, vbGreen, vbRed)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This Works! Thank you very much for your time, your help is much appreciated. There was only one little mistake you made. ppm * 0.9 = 900000, I need an offset of 10.000. Changed it to 0.99. and 1.01.

Comment: Would "Criteria1:=">=" & ppm - 10000" and "Criteria2:="<=" & ppm + 10000" also work? because ppm *0.99/1.01 would only work for 1000000.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a loop that goes over the rows (row 2 to last row minus 10). In the loop, there'd be a nested loop going over the next 9 rows and checking if the criteria are met. Use a pseudo-continue statement whenever criteria are not met. Have the coloring code go after the nested loop, so it's only executed if criteria were met.

As for the red cell in case nothing matched, a simple boolean flag would do.

Code outline:

```
Sub doThis()

    dim found as boolean
    found = false

    dim i as long, j as long, lastline as long
    lastline = mySheet.Range(relevantRange).End(xlUp).row

    for i = 2 to lastline - 10
        for j = i to 10
            if not (cells(i, relevantColumn) + 10001 > cells(j, relevantColumn) _
                and cells(i, relevantColumn) - 10001 < cells(j, relevantColumn)) then
                GoTo continue
            end if
        next
        range(relevantColumn & i & ":" & relevantColumn & i + 9).Interior.ColorIndex = vbGreen
        found = true
        exit sub
continue:
    next

    if not found then
        'coloring code
    end if

End Sub
```

I did not test this since I don't have appropriate data. Post a comment if you need help.

Comment: Thanks for your time but user3598756 his awnser works for me!